# ModelForm __init__ being called a ridiculous amount of times

Tags: python, django, django-views, modelform

Just going to put some code and explain at the bottom.

```
# modelforms.py
#
class MyModelModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(MyModelModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print '__init__'

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ('my_fk', )
```

Here I am using django-vanilla-views

```
# views.py
#
class MyCreateView(NoAdminNoStaffLoginRequiredMixin, HasPermissionsMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'modelform_create.html'
    form_class = MyOtherModelModelForm # this modelform isn't important
    required_permission = 'create_model'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('mymodel_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # FIXME: form's __init__ being called a lot
        MyModelFormset = modelformset_factory(
            MyModel, form=MyModelModelForm, extra=4, max_num=10, validate_max=True)

        if self.request.POST:
            formset = MyModelFormset(
                self.request.POST,
                queryset=MyModel.objects.none(),
                form_kwargs={'request': self.request})
        else:
            formset = MyModelFormset(
                queryset=MyModel.objects.none(),
                form_kwargs={'request': self.request})

        print formset.total_form_count() # 4, which makes sense

        context['formset'] = formset

        return context
```

MyModelModelForm `__init__` gets called 18 times. Yeah, I was wondering if I could get that from not happening.

Reason being I would like it to not be called multiple times is I query the DB for `forms.ChoiceField(choices=...)`, which queries the DB that many times unnecessarily. Or if there is a better spot for populating choices (NOTE: I cannot just do it in the same space where the field is declared.) It is a mixin that populates this certain field.

If any more info is needed let me know. I had to trim down the code for only relevant info.